# Problem with encoding using AntiXss library

Tags: asp.net, encoding, antixsslibrary

I am using AntiXss library 4.0 for encoding text before displaying on the asp page.

```
 <asp:Label Text="text" runat="server" ID="lblTest" />

<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lsbTest">
</asp:ListBox>
```

This is the asp code. In the PageLoad I am writing

```
 lblTest.Text = Encoder.HtmlEncode("test & test");
        lsbTest.Items.Add(new ListItem(Encoder.HtmlEncode("test & test"), Encoder.HtmlEncode("test & test")));
```

Here, when the text in the label is rendered, it shows & as &, but in the case of Listbox, & is rendered as `&amp;`. But, I want this to be rendered as & even in listbox. 
How to do this?
Thanks,
Ashwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items in a `ListItem` are automatically encoded for you. If you have configured the AntiXSS library as default `HttpEncoder`, you wont have to encode it manually. If you didn't configure it, ASP.NET will use the default (less secure) encoding.

To configure it, [read](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx) this article.

Comment: Thanks, Can u tell me how to know if a string is encoded or not, so that double encoding can be avoided?

Comment: That's a total new question, which I don't know the answer to :-). You might try asking this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.